# Is There any option to copy pptx slide to docx using java

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, powerpoint, docx4j

I am creating my project document using docx4j. I am having project images in pptx files. I have to add the pptx slide as image in my docx file.

I am converting the pptx slides to images and placing the image into my document using poi 4.1.0. But the accuracy of the output image is not good.

```
public static void pptToImageConversion() throws IOException {

FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("D:/Tmp/Slide/test.pptx");
XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(is);
Dimension pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();
List<XSLFSlide> slide = ppt.getSlides();

for (int i = 0; i < slide.size(); i++) {
System.out.println("Started Writing slide-" + (i + 1));
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(pgsize.width,pgsize.height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();
graphics.setPaint(Color.white);
graphics.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, pgsize.width, pgsize.height));
slide.get(i).draw(graphics);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:/Tmp/Slide/png/" + (i+1) + ".png");
javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(img, "png", out);
out.close();
System.out.println("End Writing slide-" + (i + 1));
}
```

The output image of the above code is not accurate. It is giving me alignment and color issues. I want to know two things

1. Am I using wrong code for converting slides into images?
2. How to import pptx slide into my word document directly? (without converting the slide into image)

Comment: You could OLE embed it, but that functionality is in Docx4j Enterprise.

Comment: @JasonPlutext: Is there any way to try Docx4j Entrprice before buying the license. could you give me an example code to use OLE

Comment: Trial/eval link https://www.plutext.com/m/index.php/products scroll to the bottom.  You'll find sample code in the zip file.